# Google Cloud SQL Server and Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-sql

I am having trouble connecting a Node.js application (that uses express) I am running on my computer to Google Cloud SQL Server. How would I go about doing this? I am able to connect and make changes using SQL Server Management Studio. I have tried to connect using the public IP address in the overview tab for the database and I have tried connecting using Google cloud proxy. The former would result in an error that said `ETIMEDOUT` the latter would result in a handshake inactivity error. I also tried using the socketPath field and that resulted in the error `ENOENT` so I believe I may not be formatting the input for that field correctly. Does anyone have any insight on what I am doing wrong or have any good examples?

Comment: Please provide code example that you have and exact error codes

Comment: are you running app engine flex o standard environment?